# Как удалить объект во вложенном объекте по значению?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Есть такая JSON строка:

```
[
    {
        "room_name":"GUEST1_/#hci2aC-nD_EeQDzuAAAB",
        "owner":"/#hci2aC-nD_EeQDzuAAAB",
        "name_owner":"GUEST1"
    },
    {
        "room_name":"GUEST2_/#wslEqNbGi_feQ_9RAAAC",
        "owner":"/#wslEqNbGi_feQ_9RAAAC",
        "name_owner":"GUEST2"
    }
]
```

После парсинга в Nodejs получается соответствующий объект.

Как можно удалить полностью один массив по значению, например "owner", чтобы осталась только другая строка?

Или нужно как-то парсить не в объекты, а в ассоц массив и уже с ним работать?

Comment: что за каша с определениями массивов и объектов?

Comment: Да, беда с этим. Читал про них, но не понял разницы, если просто применять JSON.parse();

Comment: На самом деле все просто: если скобочки квадратные - `[]` это массив, если фигурные - `{}` это объект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для фильтрации массива можно применить [функцию `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var res = arr.filter(el=>el.owner != ...)
```

В `res` вернутся строки, в которых owner не равен указанному.